# Setting geometry types importing to PostGIS with OGR

Tags: postgis, spatial-database, ogr2ogr, import

I'm using `ogr2ogr` to import data into a PostGIS database. Each dataset I need to import has (theoretically) the same exact data structure, but it appears that they are *not* the same geometry types. Example, I've already imported the first layer, and there's a layer called "streets". Running this command, I import the first feature class from the first database (I have GDAL configured to read `.mdb`):

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=database port=5432" city1.mdb streets -nln streets -nlt MULTILINESTRING -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geometry
```

When I go to append (using the `-append` flag) the same streets layer from `city2.mdb`, I get this error (presumably due to conflicting geometry types for the two "streets" layers:

```
Warning 1: Geometry to be inserted is of type 3D Line String, whereas the layer geometry type is 3D Multi Line String.
Insertion is likely to fail
ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed.
ERROR:  Geometry type (LineString) does not match column type (MultiLineString)
```

Is there a straightforward way with `ogr2ogr` to cast geometries to the same type on import? Or a way to handle this by predefining the schema and geometries for each table beforehand?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `-nlt` option. In this case you want:

```
-nlt MULTILINESTRING
```

There is also `PROMOTE_TO_MULTI` (GDAL 1.10 and later), which chooses either `MULTILINESTRING` or `MULTIPOLYGON` depending on the input layer. The [use case for this](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-September/034128.html) is "doing a mass conversion of shapefiles that [mix] different  types of geometries".